# iOS Programming with Web database interface

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am programming in Obj-C with X-code and I want to create a project where I am able to pull up information from the database that I have created in my website.

I understand that this can be safely and easily done with a mobile web application. Any ideas how on how I parse the database with Objective-C and X-code ?

Please reply.

Thanks and regards,
-Venkat

Comment: Ron's answer of how to program a simple web service is good, but you mentioned "parse." What kind of data is your website providing? The best for iOS is a REST interface that returns a simple format back, generally in XML or JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken the iOS SDK can not connect directly to your database. The way I do this is to send out a post request using the ASIHTTP class and then parse the returned data from your website. Read the documentation [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).
This is an example of how to use it from one of my own applications:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yoursite.com/page.php"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:variable1 forKey:@"key1"];
[request setPostValue:variable2 forKey:@"key2"];
[request setPostValue:variable3 forKey:@"key3"];
[request setDelegate:self];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

You then catch the result with the following code:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    //do your parsing here
}
}
```

Don't forget to include the required files and classes to your app. But it's all explained in the documentation.

Hope it helps a bit!

Comment: +1 ASIHTTP is good, but the built-in NSURLConnection can handle most of the common cases pretty simply without having to add thirdparty code. If your needs are complex, though, ASIHTTP is a nice addition.

Comment: You are right Rob, NSURLConnection does the job, but I really like the easyness of ASIHTTP in adding variables and other stuff to request. Lazy I guess :-)

Comment: Hello. Which documentation are you talking about ?? Are there any books/ articles which provide this work with an example ???

Comment: @VS click on the link where it says 'documentering here'. It's an entire site full of examples and explanation. Or Google ASIHTTP, that should get you started!